# Angular Material: changing font size of input clips text

Tags: angular, material-design, angular-material

I am modifying the font size of my Angular Material `input`s to 28px, but this is causing [the descenders](https://www.canva.com/learn/typography-terms/) of some characters to be clipped, like the 'g' in this example:

[image]

Can't for the life of me work out how to solve this. Any ideas anyone? Which classes do I need to augment?

I modified my component in SCSS like this:

```
input {
  font-size: 28px;
}
```

Comment: How did you modified the font size. Share your CSS.

Comment: Have done above.

Comment: Works ok here - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gjkbqm - but you could have global styles which are being applied. Some `padding-bottom` should fix it though. You may also want to show the relevant HTML code as well.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you want to change `font-size` for `mat-form-field`, you should apply the style to the `mat-form-field` element, not the `input` element. If you don't, certain parts of the form field may not respond properly (style wise). You should also make sure you set `line-height` appropriately for the same reason.

If you plan to adhere to material design, then you should be using the utilities and creating your style using theming/typography with `mat-typography-level-to-styles` and one of the Material Design specified typography levels. This *should* be done with the typography utilities but you can do it manually. See https://material.angular.io/guide/typography for details.

For example, 24px is the font size for what Angular Material calls `headline` (H5 in material design - not an H5 element) so your style should implement the appropriate headline specification (according to Angular Material's implementation of H5):

```
.input-headline {
    font-size: 28px;
    line-height: 32px;
    font-weight: 400;
}
```

Angular Material has convenience style classes that do this for you. For headline it is `mat-headline` so you could easily just do:

```
<mat-form-field class="mat-headline">
```

Note that 28px is not a material design specified font level: https://material.io/design/typography/the-type-system.html#type-scale.

Answer (score 4):

When you use material theme it's possible with material to define typography

```
$typography: mat-typography-config(
  $input: mat-typography-level(14px, 1.125, 400),
);
@include mat-core($typography);
```